# Epiphany hat in another language except on Winterbash Hat List

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I just got the Epiphany hat, but it had a weird description:

[image: Epiphany hat]

Seeing this, I went to the hat list on the Winter Bash page to see if this was just a secret hat with a different description since these descriptions are the unlocking requirements except for secret hats (but generally it's *"this is a secret hat"*)

[image: Hat List]

So I decided to click on it here, and the weird text has appeared again:

[image: Epiphany Hat on Hat List]

I get the feeling this is another language, but why is this hat doing this?

Comment: It is explained in that answer: The hat has the subtitle _La Befana vien di notte Con le scarpe tutte rotte_, which is the [Itialian children's rhyme sung on Epiphany](http://www.mamalisa.com/?t=es&p=3102).